# How can I use emoji on my Mac as easily as I can on my iPhone?

Tags: macos, emoji

Is there any easy way for me to add emoji to a document or email when I’m using my Mac?

I know I can set up up an emoji viewer in the menu bar via Apple > System Preferences > Keyboard, but I find this very clumsy to use.

A keyboard shortcut would be fantastic, but when I checked the Mac Keyboard Shortcuts https://support.apple.com/HT201236 page on Apple’s website I didn’t see any emoji shortcuts listed.

What’s the easiest way for me to insert emoji on a Mac (one without a Touch Bar)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Mac Emoji keyboard. All you need to do is press the <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>spacebar</kbd> keys and this brings up the following:

[image: Emoji viewer]

Once the Emoji keyboard appears, just click on the emoji you want to insert!

**NOTE:** - For the emoji to actually insert, your cursor needs to be located within a text document, text field, search field, etc. Basically anywhere you could normally type text.